# Switch syntax highlighting of open buffer from web-mode (freemarker) to sql

Tags: syntax, web-mode, highlighting, sql

we use web-mode (freemarker engine) to edit source files that contain freemarker directives and a lot of SQL.

Editing in web-mode (freemarker engine) works fine.

It would be very helpful if we could switch syntax highlighting from web-mode (freemarker) to SQL for open buffers.
Is that possible?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Meikel

Comment: Is `web-mode` a major mode (in which case it conflicts with `sql-mode`)? If so, you can always try copying the definition of `font-lock-keywords` for `sql-mode` and use it with `web-mode`. See how `sql-mode` adds its font-locking, and try using the same code with `web-mode`.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble determining what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to extend `web-mode` in some way, or do you want to replace it wholesale?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I added

```
(add-hook 'sql-mode-hook 'sql-highlight-postgres-keywords)
```

to my .emacs.

Now I can change between modes by M-x sql-mode and M-x web-mode.